# When to use Extensions vs Interfaces in AirTable?

Tags: airtable

The tools available in AirTable's Extensions and Interfaces are so similar! I'm having difficulty separating my use cases for them. I'm in charge of creating simple data dashboards for my small nonprofit, which is fun, but I feel as though I've duplicated views.

Does anyone have any examples to share of what helps them differentiate when to use extensions and when to use interfaces? Just curious to see what's out there!

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are more for proper BI dashboards, like an alternative to Tableau, and are for an audience that doesn't need to see granular data. Extensions are more geared for those referencing the base's underlying data, and even though there are data vis tools, 1) you probably wouldn't use extensions for a BI dashboard replacement and 2) a lot of the extensions are for very specific use cases, like editing a JSON field in the base